# ExecuteNonQuery is not resolving parameters passed to it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am attempting to add the variable `newRetentionLimit` to a table in Microsoft SQL Server. I pass the value I want to insert into a parameter and then run `ExecuteNonQuery`. I get no errors back but the `newRetentionLimit` isn't placed into the table. I have debugged to make sure that `newRetentionLimit` isn't null and is an actual integer.

The problem appears to be that `ExecuteNonQuery` isn't retrieving the parameter value based on the name I put in the script. It appears its just trying to run the script with the parameter name. Anyone have any idea why?

```
if (request.SystemSettings.Any(s => s.SettingName.Equals("HISTORYRETENTIONDAYS")))
{
    var entities = entityRepo.GetList();

    var newRetentionLimit = request.SystemSettings.Find(setting => setting.SettingName.Equals("HISTORYRETENTIONDAYS")).SettingValue.ToInt();
    var requestContext = new RequestContext();

    var sqlParameter = new List<SqlParameter> {
                    SqlParameterMaker.MakeTypedValueParameter("@retentionValue",newRetentionLimit, SqlDbType.Int)
    };

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var sql = $@"ALTER TABLE [data].[t{entity.Name}] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [hist].[t{entity.Name}], HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = @retentionValue DAYS));";
        requestContext.DatabaseContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, sqlParameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can't use a variable there, it needs to be a literal. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ce124887a7417046025acc400c88ec2)

Comment: @Larnu: Where? .

Comment: `HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = @retentionValue DAYS` @Robert. The value of the Retention Period *must* be a literal.

Comment: Or concatenated, like the OP is doing everywhere else.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns a number indicating number of rows changed.  If you are getting zero you can check the log records in database by using SQL Server Management and looking under Management.  The log file should give a the reason why no rows got changed.

Comment: I would *expect* a DDL statement to return 0 rows effected anyway, @jdweng . If it did return a number > 0, then that would mean that there was a DDL trigger fired that doesn't have `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.

Comment: *"Or concatenated, like the OP is doing everywhere else."* And not caring for SQL Injection attacks, concerningly, @RobertHarvey . ╮（╯＿╰）╭

Comment: I would think if the query was not successful it would return zero and greater than zero if successful.  But the Microsoft documentation says "rows".  The OPs query is not modifying rows so the documentation is flawed.

Comment: @Larnu : Then how do you know if it failed?

Comment: It would raise an exception. It doesn't just silently fail and leave it to the end user to check a return code on the SQL Server side.

Comment: What is the type of  `requestContext.DatabaseContext`? Is this some standard Microsoft class? If it is your own class does the implementation of `ExecuteNonQuery` eat errors instead of bubbling them up?

Comment: @Larnu: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I posted the solution. Thanks for every ones help!

Comment: @Larnu Actually it would return `-1`. *"If no statements are detected that contribute to the count, the return value is -1."*

Comment: Blarg, I dislike that , @Charlieface . How does one "affect -1 rows"...

Comment: @Larnu It's called a "magic" number. Note that `Nullable<int>` didn't exist back in 2003, and we should be thankful they didn't return `object` which could alternatively be `DBNull.Value`.......

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that still allows me to maintain the use of SqlParameter

```
if (request.SystemSettings.Any(s => s.SettingName.Equals("HISTORYRETENTIONDAYS")))
        {
            var entities = entityRepo.GetList();
            var newRetentionLimit = request.SystemSettings.Find(setting => setting.SettingName.Equals("HISTORYRETENTIONDAYS")).SettingValue.ToInt();
            var requestContext = new RequestContext();
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>{
                    new SqlParameter("@entityName", entity.Name),
                    new SqlParameter("@retentionPeriod", newRetentionLimit)
                };
                var sql = "EXEC('ALTER TABLE [data].[t' + @entityName + '] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = ' + @retentionPeriod + ' DAYS))');";
                requestContext.DatabaseContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, sqlParameters.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

Comment: `'ALTER TABLE [data].' + QUOTENAME('t' + @entityName) + '] SET...` might be wiser, in case there are table names that need escaping

Comment: It should be noted that using parameters and concatenating them into a string in SQL is no safer than not using parameters at all.